# Event Action displays undefined in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to track a html5 video for which I have created a Tag with custom HTML using the source code from this link (https://www.thyngster.com/tracking-html5-videos-gtm/). Then I created data layer variables, eventAction, eventCategory and eventLabel. All of these seem to work fine in the debug mode of Tag Manager. However, in Google Analytics, the event Action shows "undefined". I don't know where I have missed out. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screen shot of the tag set up and the trigger? I would assume the tag is firing before the event parameters are pushed into the datalayer

Comment: @Jesse It is now showing in the real-time events but not populating on the goals.

Comment: It would show in behavior > top events. To make it a goal you need to go to admin and create a goal using event goal event category = HTML5